# Efficient way to call a plain https url 1 billion times

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, url, https

I have been recently working on a scenario, in which I need to pass a collection of big data (~ 1 billion) one by one to a specific client by hitting a  plain https url eg : `https://www.example.com/field1="";field2=""`.

Here `field1` & `field2` will have data which will be sent across. I have been trying to implement the solution using spark scala, by leveraging the inherent parallel computing architecture to speed up the process, but the solution is not perfectly up to the mark.

```
import java.net.URL
import java.io._
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

val counter = spark.sparkContext.longAccumulator

val df = spark.read.table("")
df .repartition(1000).rdd.foreachPartition (

           part => {

                 part.foreach( row => {
                      val ID = row.getAs[String]("id")
                      val EXTID = row.getAs[String]("externId")
                      val httpsURL = "https://www.hello.com/activityi;dc_pre=CLzntvL5ueQCFZmsdwoddOwChw;src=6038155;type=neus;cat=ckt_b0;u100="+EXTID+";dc_lat=;dc_muid="+ID+";tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;tfua=;npa=;ord=1?"
                      val myURL:URL = new URL(httpsURL)
                      val  conn:HttpsURLConnection= myURL.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpsURLConnection]
                      conn.connect()
                      if(conn.getResponseCode >= 200  && conn.getResponseCode() <=400){
                           counter.adad(1)
                      }
                      else{}
                      conn.disconnect()
                 })
           }
)
```

It would be good, if someone can suggest a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: Are you using AWS EMR or your own self-managed cluster?

Comment: @hephalump, i am using emr here, on that front , can you suggest any specific task/core node  to use for supporting such kind of use cas